# How to parallel variadic function with TBB parallel_for?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, tbb, variadic-functions

I have a template variadic function like this that need to parallelize with TBB `parallel_for` function

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename... T3>
void func(T1 t1, T2 t2, std::size_t n, T3... t3)
```

I first tried to use lambda function, it is able to catch the variadic arguments. It compiled with clang using C++11 feature.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename... T3>
void parallel_func(T1 t1, T2 t2, std::size_t n, T3 t3...){
     range r(n);
     apply_func = [=](range r){  //clang 6.1 can catch t3... here, gcc 4.8.3 could not
         std::size_t offset = r.begin();
         std::size_t n = r.end() -r.begin();
         func(t1, t2, n, (t3+offset)...);
     };
     tbb::parallel_for(r, apply_func);
}
```

However, the cluster I use don't have a compiler to support this feature. I have to give up lambda function and write a class and pass it to `parallel_for` function.
I tried:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename... T3>
class ApplyFunc{
     ApplyFunc(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3... t3){
         t1_ = t1;
         t2_ = t2;
         t3_ = t3...;

     }
      void operator(range r){
         std::size_t offset = r.begin();
         std::size_t n = r.end() -r.begin();
         func(T1, T2, n, (T3+offset)...);
      }
      private:
         T1 t1_;
         T2 t2_;
         T3... t3_;
}
```

apparently, variadic variable is not supported. I tried
         std::tuple t3_;
However, I am not able to convert `std::tuple<T3...>` back into variadic arguments.

Comment: You are compiling the code on cluster where you don't have c++11 support ?

Comment: @Jagannath it is gcc 4.8. Which does not support lambda with variadic arguments.

Comment: Sorry could not understand exactly. `parallel_for` takes start and end index to iterate through. So how are you passing the class to it ? Could you use `parallel_for_each` and take all these arguments in a `std::tuple` and have `begin` and `end` in your class. Will that work ?

Comment: What do you want to parallelize? call `ApplyFunc::operator()` to range `r` in parallel?

Comment: @yohjp TBB will split range `r`, so the value of `n` will be different for each piece of range `r`. Let's say T3 is a pointer type. `t3+n` will be different when `parallel_for` call the function `operator(range& r)`

Comment: When range has 4 elements and TBB splits it two subranges, you want to parallel invoke `func(t1,t2,(t3+0),(t3+1))` and `func(t1,t2,(t3+2),(t3+3))` ?

Comment: @yohjp Sorry, I didn't explain very well. I made an update. Let's say we have two data with 4 elements, and t3 and t4 are pointer to the data. TBB splits it two subranges. it will call `func(t1, t2, 2, (t3+0), (t4+0))` and `func(t1, t2, 2, (t3+2), (t4+2))`. It uses variadic T3 so that you can pass any number of data to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::tuple<Ts...>` to hold variadic values, and expand it for function invocation with [the indices trick](http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/tips-and-tricks:indices). C++14 Standard Library provides [`std::index_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) for this purpose.

```
#include <tuple>

// forward compatibility for C++14 Standard Library
namespace cxx14 {
template<std::size_t...> struct index_sequence{};

template<std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct make_index_sequence : make_index_sequence<N-1, N-1, Is...>{};

template<std::size_t... Is>
struct make_index_sequence<0, Is...> : index_sequence<Is...>{};
}

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename... Ts>
class ApplyFunc{
public:
  ApplyFunc(T1 t1, T2 t2, Ts... ts)
    : t1_(t1), t2_(t2), pack_(ts...) {}

  template<std::size_t... Is>
  void call(range r, cxx14::index_sequence<Is...>){
    std::size_t offset = r.begin();
    std::size_t n = r.end() - r.begin();
    func(t1_, t2_, n, (std::get<Is>(pack_)+offset)...);
  }

  void operator()(range r){
    call(r, cxx14::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>());
  }
private:
  T1 t1_;
  T2 t2_;
  std::tuple<Ts...> pack_;
};
```

Comment: does gcc 4.8.3 support this?

Comment: gcc 4.8.2 does and 4.8.3 will be. [LiveDemo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/vSGnMVT6UqpuQaRO)